# Django AppRegistryNotReady when running Unittests from vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

My UnitTest test cases in a Django project run fine when running them directly from the Django utility (`python manage.py test`). However, when trying to run them from VSCode's test explorer, I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`. I found several similar questions that were already answered here on SO, but none of the solutions seem to work. Here's what I tried:

- import my classes (e.g. `models`) within the `SetUpTestData` method and the actual test methods of the test class, rather than at the top of the file. This seemed to help a bit, in the sense that the tests now do show up in the test explorer (previously they didn't), but I still get an error when running them.
- set the `DJANGO_SETINGS_MODULE` environment variable at the top of the file containing the test class:

  ```
   import os
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
  ```
- add a `.env` file to my root directory, containing `DJANGO_SETINGS_MODULE = my_project.settings`
- add a configuration with purpose `debug-test` to `launch.json`:

  ```
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Django test",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
           "args": [
               "test"
           ],
           "purpose": ["debug-test"],
           "django": true,
           "justMyCode": true
       }
   ]
  ```
- remove `tests.py` from my app folder, as my tests are stored in a separate folder (and apparently Django can't have both)

My folder structure looks like this:

```
root
  |_ my_app
      |_ tests
          |_ __init__.py
          |_ test_models.py
  |_ my_project
```

For the sake of completeness, I have the following in settings.json:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        ".",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

Is there any way to make VSCode's test explorer play nice with Django and UnitTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do the following steps:

1. Create a `__init__.py` file in your `tests` directory (if it doesn't already exist), and add the following code:

```py
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
django.setup()
```

These codes manually set the Django settings module and initializes Django.

2. In your `settings.json`, change the `python.testing.unittestArgs` to point to your `tests` directory:

```json
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./my_app/tests", 
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

This tells VS Code to look for tests in the `my_app/tests` directory.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem that I reported initally, but there's some strange side effect now: when I run `python manage.py test`, the test cases run in their own 'environment' in the sense that they are unaware of any data that might already be on my database. When I run from vscode test explorer however, my tests are polluted by the data that is in the database and I get unexpected results. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @NiH Hi， glad to know this solved your initial problem.  You could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. For your further problem, you could create a new issue and give an case for a minimally reproducible issue along with detailed information。